# Installing magento on local virtual host windows 7

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am trying to install magento on a virtual host in my system running with XAMPP

I have done following till now :

Added lines in the hosts file under windows/system32/driver/host

```
192.168.1.69       magento2.hue
192.168.1.69       www.magento2.hue
```

Then added code in httpd-vhosts.conf in XAMPP folder

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.69:80
<VirtualHost magento2.hue>
    ServerAdmin magento2.hue
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/mag_domain2/httpdocs/"
    ServerName magento2.hue
    ServerAlias www.magento2.hue
    ErrorLog "C:/www/mag_domain2/httpdocs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/www/mag_domain2/httpdocs/access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/www/mag_domain2/httpdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restarted Apache and Mysql, but the site i.e magento2.hue is not loading.

Can you please figure out if i am doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Check the basic things first, ping www.magento.hue. Then "telnet www.magento2.hue 80" let me know the results. I suspect however that windows firewall is causing an issue.

Comment: i have checked disabling the firewalls, same results

Comment: And the other tests, ping and telnet?

Answer (score 0):

try with below httpd.conf setting it working at my end

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/yourmagentosetup" 
 ServerName magento2.hue
</VirtualHost>
```

hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: @SKV,it would be glad for me to just vote up our answer so someone can use in future if they have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my,

I just figure it out.. i have previously added another vhost which points to 192.168.1.59 and is working fine

I just needed to point new one to the same IP and change the ServerName to magento2.hue instead of magento.hue as was of previous one.

it works now.

Thanks liyakat and Arjun for viewing this question.